# Laravel 5.5 conditional form request validation rule on update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-5.5

I created a validation rule for the image form.

It works fine on store method but I do not want the image field to be required on update because I may only update the title for example.

```
class ImageRequest extends Request
{   
    /**
     * Rules array
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|string|between:3,60',
        'alt'   => 'sometimes|string|between:3,60',
        'image' => 'required|image|max:4000|dimensions:min_width=200,min_height=200',
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return $this->rules;
    }
}
```

For **unique** validation we can add custom query conditions:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id')
```

or

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('account_id', 1);
})
```

Is it a clean way to achieve something similar for **required**?

Apply **required** only for new images.

Comment: please accept any of the answer which solved your problem to close this question and upvote any/all answer that has helped to fix your problem

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found a solution.

I renamed **image** into **file**.

The route is **homestead.app/images/1** on **update** and **homestead.app/images** on **store** so the **$image** property will be **$this->image = 1** on **update** and ***$this->image = null*** on **store**.

```
class ImageRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Rules array
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'title'=> 'required|string|between:3,60',
        'alt'  => 'sometimes|string|between:3,60',
        'file' => [
            'image',
            'max:4000',
            'dimensions:min_width=200,min_height=200',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $this->rules['file'][] = is_null($this->image) ? 'required' : 'sometimes';

        return $this->rules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you Can use switch statement inside rule

```
 public function rules()
    {

        switch ($this->method()) {
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE': {
                return [];
            }
            case 'POST': {

                      return [
                          'first_name'=>'required',
                          'last_name'=>'required',
                        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$this->id,
                          'password'=>'',
                          'dob'=>'required',
                          'phone_one'=>'required',
                          'phone_two'=>'required',
                          //'user_role'=>'required',
                      //    'profile_image'=>'required'
                      ];
            }
            case 'PUT':
            case 'PATCH': {
                return [

                ];
            }
            default:break;
        }
```

Also you can use condtion like on update yuo have id so based on that you can check whether its update or insert since on insert you dont have id so

Answer (score 0):

Create another class that extends the Request class, DI that into your update controller action

```
class UpdateImageRequest extends Request
{   
    /**
     * Rules array
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|string|between:3,60',
        'alt'   => 'sometimes|string|between:3,60'
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return $this->rules;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the backup solution (including: 'image' => 'sometimes|image|max:4000|dimensions:min_width=200,min_height=200') but I was hoping to reuse the same validation class using something like :

Rule::sometimes('required', function ($query) {
    return $query->where('image_id', 1);
});

Comment: you can extend from this class the normal class you only change the rules

Answer (score 0):

much better way is to use `nullable` in Laravel 5.5 validations

Ref [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-nullable)

> The field under validation may be null. This is particularly useful
>   when validating primitive such as strings and integers that can
>   contain null values.

```
class ImageRequest extends Request
{   
    /**
     * Rules array
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|string|between:3,60',
        'alt'   => 'nullable|string|between:3,60',
        'image' => 'nullable|image|max:4000|dimensions:min_width=200,min_height=200',
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return $this->rules;
    }
}
```

However I have used recently with image and it worked like charm for me. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in this case in the other way. By default have rules for update and if it's store add required like so:

```
class ImageRequest extends Request
{   
    /**
     * Rules array
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|string|between:3,60',
        'alt'   => 'sometimes|string|between:3,60',
        'image' => 'image|max:4000|dimensions:min_width=200,min_height=200',
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = $this->rules;

        if ($this->isMethod('POST')) {
           $rules['image'] = 'required|' . $rules['image']
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```